# About two definitions of a complete lattice. ("Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" by Kazuo Matsuzaka)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Toplogy" by Kazuo Matsuzaka (in Japanese).

In this book, the definition of a complete lattice is the following:

> Let $M$ be a partially ordered set.
> If any ***non-empty*** subset of $M$ has a supremum and an infimum (in $M$), then $M$ is called a complete lattice.

The definition of a complete lattice in Wikipedia is the following (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice):

> In mathematics, a complete lattice is a partially ordered set in which ***all*** subsets have both a supremum (join) and an infimum (meet).

I think the two definitions above are different.
If the two definitions above are different, then is Matsuzaka' definiton bad?

Let $M$ be a partially ordered set.
Suppose any non-empty subset of $M$ has a supremum and an infimum (in $M$).
Any element of $M$ is an upper bound of $\emptyset$ and any element of $M$ is a lower bound of $\emptyset$.
So, if $M$ has a maximum element, then $\emptyset$ has an infimum and if $M$ has a minimum element, then $\emptyset$ has a supremum.
If $M$ doesn't have a maximum element or a minimum element, then the Wikipedia's definition says $M$ is not a complete lattice and the Matsuzaka's definition says $M$ is a complete lattice.

Is there a partially ordered set $M$ such that any non-empty subset of $M$ has a supremum and an infimum (in $M$) and $M$ doesn't have a maximum element or a minimum element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two definitions are equivalent - at least, under the additional assumption that the lattice $M$ itself is nonempty. (Some texts require structures, such as lattices, to be nonempty - but not all do!) The point is that, switching sups and infs, $M$ itself can do what we want $\emptyset$ to do (so to speak): the supremum of the emptyset is the infimum of *the whole lattice*, and similarly the infimum of the emptyset is the supremum of *the whole lattice*.

Note that the "inf/sup switch" here is crucial: in a *semilattice* context we do indeed get two different notions which differ only by the requirement of a greatest/least element (depending on whether we're looking at complete upper or complete lower semilattices). But with both sups and infs, the two definitions in the OP coincide.

Comment: They are not quite equivalent since $M$ could be empty.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah, I tend to require structures to be nonempty. But I'll add that.

Comment: Noah Schweber, Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The two definitions are almost, but not quite, equivalent. The one difference is the empty set.

Comment: Not sure why this got a -1, it's short but it's objectively correct.

Comment: Mark Saving, Thank you very much for your answer.